# Use a batch script to search for a text on multiple files and rename the file if find the text inside

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I need to create a batch script that loops through some files in a folder, search for some text written inside, compare with the texts I have in a array, and if find a match, rename that file using that text as the new name. The code is working more or less, because it only works for the first item on the array and for the first file.
So, what am I missing?
Thanks for any help.

```
cd C:\folder1

set nomes[0]=Report 1
set nomes[1]=Report 2
set nomes[2]=Report 3
set nomes[3]=Report 4
set nomes[4]=Report 5

set SearchString="18/08/21"

rem ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
rem ////// loop read all files in current folder //////
for %%f in (*.q) do (
    set /p val=<%%f
    SET SUBSTRING=!val:~1,8!
    
    rem ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    rem ////// verify if the file has the current date inside //////
    if "!SUBSTRING!"=="%SearchString%" (
        
        rem ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        rem ////// verify if the file has the hour above 13 hours  /////
        if  "!val:~10,5!" GTR "13" (

            set linhanome=
            for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%I in (%%f) do if not defined linhanome ( 
                set "linhanome=%%~I"
                
                rem //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                rem ////// verify if can find on item from the array inside the file /////
                set encontrounome=
                for /l %%n in (0,1,5) do if not defined encontrounome  (

                    set findtext=!nomes[%%n]!
                    set findfile=%%f

                    findstr /C:!findtext! !findfile! * 2>nul
                    IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (
                        ECHO CASE TRUE
                        set "encontrounome=true"
        
                        ren "%%f" "!findtext!.txt"
                    )
 
                )
            )                       
        )
    )
)
```

All the files are like this:

```
"18/08/21 14:45                                                                                      Page   1"
"someradomtext        someradomtext                                  Report 1
```

EDITED  The code that is working now, after some help and a few changes.

```
cd C:\folder1

set nomes[0]=Report 1
set nomes[1]=Report 2
set nomes[2]=Report 3
set nomes[3]=Report 4
set nomes[4]=Report 5

set SearchString="18/08/21"

rem ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
rem ////// loop read all files in current folder //////
for %%f in (*.q) do (
    set /p val=<%%f
    SET SUBSTRING=!val:~1,8!
    
    rem ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    rem ////// verify if the file has the current date inside //////
    if "!SUBSTRING!"=="%SearchString%" (
        
        rem ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        rem ////// verify if the file has the hour above 13 hours  /////
        if  "!val:~10,2!" GTR "13" (
                
            rem //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            rem ////// verify if can find on item from the array inside the file /////
            for /l %%n in (0,1,12) do (

                set "findtext=!nomes[%%n]!"
                set "findfile=%%f"
        
                IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (
                    rem ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    rem ////// get the file and copy to the right location /////
                    FOR /f %%a IN ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr /m /C:"!findtext!" "%%f"') DO (
                        ECHO %%a      !findtext! 
                        copy "%%a" "!findtext!.txt"
                    )
                ) 
            )
                                    
        )
    )

)

pause
```

Comment: `findstr /C:!findtext! !findfile! * 2>nul` does not really work as you want to find the string `Report 1` containing a space character. I don't know what `*` should be for on this command line, but suppressing the error message `2>nul` is definitely no good idea. I suggest to use `%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /C:"!findtext!" "!findfile!" >nul` which is most likely better in this use case (not tested by me).

Comment: If `val` begins with `"dd/MM/yy hh:mm`, why wouldn't you use `if !val:~10,2! GTR 13`, instead of `if "!val:~10,5!" GTR "13"`. _There's no need to include `:mm` in that comparison_.

Comment: ```if !val:~10,2! GTR 13``` Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm... your code is pretty confusing and the requirements are not clear...

Is the array element in *second line* of the file always? if so, you don't need to use `findstr` command, just check the second line.

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd C:\folder1

set "n=0"
for %%a in ("Report 1" "Report 2" "Report 3" "Report 4" "Report 5") do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "nomes[!n!]=%%a"
)

set "SearchString=18/08/21"

rem Loop read all files
for %%f in (*.q) do (

   rem Read first two lines
   (set /P "val=" & set /P "linhanome=") < "%%f"

   rem Verify current date and hour above 13
   if "!val:~1,8!" == "%SearchString%" if "!val:~10,2!" GTR "13" (

      rem Check all array elements
      for /L %%n in (1,1,%n%) do for %%e in ("!nomes[%%n]!") do (

         rem Verify that current array element is in second line
         if "!linhanome:%%~e=!" neq "!linhanome!" (

            ren "%%f" "%%~e.txt"

         )
      )
   )
)
```

Comment: _Is the array element in second line of the file always?_  No. Sometimes it is on the third line as well.

Comment: Well, just modify my code to check just the 2nd and 3rd lines! This is much faster (and simpler) than use `findstr` on the whole file

Comment: Could explain this part `if "!linhanome:%%~e=!" neq "!linhanome!"` ? Because "!linhanome:%%~e=!" and "!linhanome!" have always the same value.

Comment: If `%%e` exists inside `!linhanome!` , then `!linhanome:%%~e=!` is _different_ than `!linhanome!`. In other words, it question if `!linhanome!` contains `%%e`

Comment: Thanks. But, would this work as well? ```if "!linhanome:%%~e=!  == True" ```

Comment: **`???`** This would work when `!linhanome!` has the value `True` only!  In Batch not exists the True/False _boolean values_, all values are strings!